# Python for loop save only last value of area?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I Used blow lines of code for contour detection and its corresponding area calculation and during printing the area all values are printed but while saving only last value got saved in CSV file

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd


img = cv2.imread('C:\pfm\segmented/L501.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


from scipy import ndimage as nd
gaussian_img = nd.gaussian_filter(image, sigma=3)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gaussian_img, 127,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#print ('No of shapes:', format(len(contours)))


for cnt in contours:

    M= cv2.moments(cnt)
        #print(M)

    if M["m00"] != 0:

        cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    else:
        cx, cy = 0,0

    center = (cx,cy)


    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0),2)


    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.imsave("C:\pfm\dataframe_csv\L501.jpg", img)

    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    print(area)

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Area'] = area
    df.to_csv("C:\pfm\dataframe_csv\L501.csv")
```

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165141/python-for-loop-save-only-last-value-to-csv).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in each loop you reset the `df` dataframe.
Try this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd


img = cv2.imread('C:\pfm\segmented/L501.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


from scipy import ndimage as nd
gaussian_img = nd.gaussian_filter(image, sigma=3)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gaussian_img, 127,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#print ('No of shapes:', format(len(contours)))

area_list = []
df = pd.DataFrame()

for cnt in contours:

    M= cv2.moments(cnt)
        #print(M)

    if M["m00"] != 0:

        cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    else:
        cx, cy = 0,0

    center = (cx,cy)


    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0),2)


    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.imsave("C:\pfm\dataframe_csv\L501.jpg", img)

    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    print(area)

    area_list.append(area)

df['Area'] = area_list
df.to_csv("C:\pfm\dataframe_csv\L501.csv")
```

Instead of append the `area` to the `df` dataframe in each loop, I append it in a list `area_list`. Note that I create this empty list before the `for` loop, to initialize it, as well as the `df` dataframe. When all loops are concluded, I create the `'Area'` column of the dataframe by saving in it the list previously generated. In this way the `df` is not empty and the code is more efficient.